# Android SQLite insertOrThrow() EXCEPTION

Tags: java, android

Everyone.

I'm developing the android app that send the data what was stored in `sqlite` database to server now.

For storing the data to `sqlite`, I used the `insertOrThrow()`.

What I wanna know is, if it happen the occur to fail to send the data, I'm afraid of the data is not exist. After sending the data, the android app shows the message "OK". In other words, there are no the record at server database.

I'll share my code.

```
public long insertSubmitRecord(int type, String data, String picPath, String vdoPath, String devicesId, String bugDesc) {
        try {
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(SQLHelper.DATA, data);
            values.put(SQLHelper.TYPE, type);

            values.put(SQLHelper.PIC_PATH, picPath);
            values.put(SQLHelper.VDO_PATH, vdoPath);
            values.put(SQLHelper.DEVICES_ID, devicesId);
            values.put(SQLHelper.BUG_DESC, bugDesc);

            values.put(SQLHelper.UPLOADERROR, 200);
            values.put(SQLHelper.UPLOADERRORINFO, "");

            return db.insertOrThrow(SQLHelper.TABLE_SUBMIT_RECORD, null, values);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("ERROR", "Failed to insert row into database");
            return -1;
        }
    }
```

How come that is not stored? ***Attention***: `insertOrThrow()`.
Please help me.

Comment: Your question is confused.  You talk about a server db, but you're using SQLite, which is a client side DB.

Comment: @Gabe Sechan, A server db is mysql, android is using SQLite. I want to send the data from sqlite to mysql.

Comment: Ok, none of your code does that, and keeping 2 databases in sync is a VERY non-trivial task (cache synchronization) unless you can add in a lot of simplifying assumptions.  We're not going to write the sync code for you, that's way beyond the scope of this question-  in fact doing it right could well be weeks of work.

Comment: I wanna know only whether the data is lose or not, when I use `insert()` or `insertOrThrow()`.